# Filling a specified area of a `Plot`

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

I have a very simple `Plot`:

```
Plot[{n, 5*n^(1/2), 4.27517*n^0.49047}, {n, 1, 50}]
```

[image]

I want to fill the areas where the two' exponential curves are greater than the blue line giving the function `n -> n`.

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Plot[{n, 5*n^(1/2), 4.27517*n^0.49047}, {n, 1, 50},
 Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {None, Opacity[0.25, Orange]}},
   3 -> {{1}, {None, Opacity[0.25, Green]}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bob Hanlon. That's awesome. Many thanks.